# Difference between getString() and getResources.getString()

Tags: android, string, resources

I noticed that the `Activity` class has two different methods to get a String resource.
This is possible by using:

- `getString(int resId)`: Return a localized string from the application's package's default string table.
- `getResources().getString(int id)`: Returns the string value associated with a particular resource ID. It will be stripped of any styled text information.

I don't understand what's the difference between both methods. Can somebody tell me?

Comment: Well, the main difference is that Activity#getString() will only access your **own** resources, whilst its completely possible to fetch another applications resources as a `Resources?? object and pick from that. I.e. in practical terms, no difference.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

They are the same as [`Activity.getString(int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/content/Context.java#Context.getString%28int%29) does exactly that:

```
 public final String getString(int resId) {
     return getResources().getString(resId);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

They are the same method, nothing special about them.

Comment: not the same method, but two different methods those do the same job.

Answer (score 2):

In Fragments you can use also `getString()` instead of `getActivity().getString()`

Comment: this does not answer the question at all