# Difference in retrieving String and String Array resources?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I'm new to Android and trying to understand the code I wrote from a tutorial. Meanwhile, I'm referencing the documentation whenever I want to really understand something.

[The documentation in question](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

That page discusses string resources.

For a string, under the **String** section it states I could retrieve a string defined in an XML file like this: `String string = getString(R.string.hello);`.

XML in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

Now, for a string array, under the **String Array** section it states I could retrieve a string string array defined in an XML file like this::

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

XML in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

How come I have to do `Resources res = getResources();` for a String Array, and not for a String in an XML file?

Would `String[] planets = getStringArray(R.array.planets_arry);` not work? Do `resources` have more methods, namely for more complex cases like String Arrays? is `getString` so simple it is fine to not need it under a resource? Where could I find a list separating what requires me to do `Resources res = getResources();` versus what doesn't require that?

Lastly, does `getResources` get me every single resource in my Android project irregardless of what XML file it may be in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How come I have to do Resources res = getResources(); for a String
>   Array, and not for a String in an XML file?

getString() is a method of your Context object (mostly an Activity but could also be a Service). The code for that method is:

```
public final String getString(int resId) {
    return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```

Meaning getString() is just a convenience method that the Context class offers. In the end both calls do the same, namely retrieve a resource through the Resource object.

> Would String[] planets = getStringArray(R.array.planets_array); not
>   work?

No because Context doesn't have a convenience method to retrieve String[].

> Do resources have more methods, namely for more complex cases like
>   String Arrays?

Yes. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html.
I leave if up to you to decide whether they are more complex than getStringArray.

> is getString so simple it is fine to not need it under a resource?

Resource does have a getString(int) method: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29)

> Where could I find a list separating what requires me to do Resources
>   res = getResources(); versus what doesn't require that?

There's no such list. The JavaDoc for Context will tell you what convenience method you got: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

> Lastly, does getResources get me every single resource in my Android
>   project regardless of what XML file it may be in?

Only if it's in a resource xml file. Layouts or Drawables can't contain String resources.

Answer (score 0):

The call `getString()` is essentially the same thing as `getResources().getStringArray()`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999591/difference-between-getstring-and-getresources-getstring) the method `getString()` is just a convenience method, because it's used so often.

```
public final String getString(int resId) {
    return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```

I'll also add that you can't use `getStringArray` in other resource files, like XML layouts, where `getString()` can be.