# Correct reading from strings.xml

Tags: android

For getting strings from strings.xml I am using this code:

```
tlacitko3.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tlacitko3));
```

But I realize that also work this one:

```
tlacitko3.setText(getString(R.string.tlacitko3));
```

So where is difference? Or is there something bad on shorter version?
Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999591/difference-between-getstring-and-getresources-getstring

Comment: Both are same. No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, Use as per your convenience

*They are two different methods that does the same job.*

I use always :

```
tlacitko3.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tlacitko3));
```

Because its easy to remember other other similar things like setting a `imageview` with a `drawable`

```
imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Answer (score 0):

They both does the same. 
If you have many. You can use below method for better coding purpose.

```
public final String getString(int resId) {
     return getResources().getString(resId);
 }
```